# Function to get year , month and day from a given age in python

Tags: python-3.x

Need a function to get DOB from a given age, so if age = 60 .. output will be in format %m,%d,%Y => '08/16/1962' .. assuming current date from date.today() is 2022-08-16 .. need to change format to be 08-16-2022

Comment: Are you assuming that today is your user's birthday?

Comment: Watch out for "today=feb 29th" and the user is 55 years old (or any other number not divisible by 4)

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
age = int(input)
today = date.today()
todayFormat = today.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
return todayFormat.replace(year = todayFormat.year - age)
```

I assumed age is a consoleinput,
date.today creates the current date as date object,
date. replace replaces certain parts of a date.

Comment: You need to use `today.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')` to get the correct format.